# KnockoutJS Nested Mapping

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using KnockoutJS, and the mapping plugin, to create a user interface.  When the page loads, it immediately calls:

```
$('document').ready ( function () {
  $.getJSON(some-url, function (data) {
    viewModel = new ViewModel(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  });
});
```

That works great.  The service at some-url responds with a JSON value of the form:

```
{ current: null
, ids: [0,1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

And I have created a method in my ViewModel class which is supposed to populate the current observable, based on the first id in the array:

```
self.head = function () {
  if (self.promptIds().length != 0) {
    var nextId = _.head(self.promptIds());
    self.promptIds(_.tail(self.promptIds()));
    $.getJSON("some-url" + "/" + nextId, function (data) {
      self.current = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Notice that I am setting `self.current` to be equal to the result of doing ko.mapping.  So I am pretty much overwriting the previous observable there.  And that explains why my bindings aren't updating, even though `self.current` is defined.

So how do I go about updating just the `viewModel.current` observable?  All I want is to parse the response of an ajax query and make it a sub-viewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought its:

```
self.current(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
```

Comment: When I do that, I end up having to put parentheses in after self.current to access the sub-object's fields:  self.current().foo().  This will work, but I wonder if there is a better way.